# What are the functional benefits of recursive scheduling in System.Reactive?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, scheduler

I'm current reading http://www.introtorx.com/ and I'm getting really interested in stripping `Subject<T>` out of my reactive code. I'm starting to understand how to encapsulate sequence generation so that I can reason better about a given sequence. I read a few SO questions and ended up reading about scheduling. Of particular interest is recursive scheduling, using the `Schedule(this IScheduler scheduler, Action<TState,Action<TState>>)`overloads - [like this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244295(v=vs.103).aspx).

The book is starting to show its age in a few areas, and the biggest i see is that it never compares its techniques to alternatives that may be achieved using the `Task` and `async/await` language features. I always end up feeling like I could write less code by ignoring the book advice and using the asynchronous toys, but the back of my mind nags me about being lazy and not learning the pattern properly.

With that, here is my question. If I wanted to schedule a sequence at an interval, support cancellation and perform work on a background thread, I might do this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sequence = Observable.Create<object>(o =>
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            DoWerk(o, cancellationTokenSource);

            return cancellationTokenSource.Cancel;
        });

        sequence.Subscribe(p => Console.Write(p));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void DoWerk(IObserver<object> o, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
    {
        string message =  "hello world!";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(250, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            o.OnNext(message[i]);

            if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        o.OnCompleted();
    }
```

Note the use of `async void` to create concurrency without explicitly borrowing a thread pool thread with `Task.Run()`. `await Task.Delay()` will, however, do just that but it will not lease the thread for long.

What are the limitations and pitfalls here? What are the reasons that you might prefer to use recursive scheduling?

Comment: Which overload of `.Create` is this? I can't get this code to compile.

Comment: The close vote on this is total garbage. Reactive has all sorts of rules about concurrency that are there for good reason. Some are counter intuitive. Please explain your vote.

Comment: _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_

Comment: Can you answer my question re the overload?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have update the code. It was terrible. Sorry about that. I still don't believe this is an more opinion based than most questions.

Comment: Questions with phrases like "What are the benefits of ...", "What are limitations ...", "What are the pitfalls ...", "What are the reasons ...", "... that you might prefer ..." all come across to me as being opinion based. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't use `await Task.Delay(250, cancellationTokenSource.Token);` as a way to slow down a loop. It's better than `Thread.Sleep(250)`, but it's still code smell to me.

I would look at it that you should use a built-in operator in preference to a roll-your-own solution like this.

The operator you need is one of the most powerful, but often overlooked. Try `Observable.Generate`. He's how:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IObservable<char> sequence = Observable.Create<char>(o =>
    {
        string message =  "hello world!";
        return
            Observable
                .Generate(
                    0,
                    n => n < message.Length,
                    n => n + 1,
                    n => message[n],
                    n => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0))
                .Subscribe(o);
    });

    using (sequence.Subscribe(p => Console.Write(p)))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is self-cancelling (when you call `.Dispose()` on the subscription) and produces values every 250.0 milliseconds.

I've continued to use the `Observable.Create` operator to ensure that the `message` variable is encapsulated within the observable - otherwise it is possible for someone to change the value of `message` as the observable is working with it and thus break it.

As an alternative, that might not be as efficient with memory, but is self-encapsulating, try this:

```
IObservable<char> sequence =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            "hello world!",
            n => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n),
            n => n.Substring(1),
            n => n[0],
            n => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0));
```

And, finally, there's nothing "recursive" about the scheduling in your question. What did you mean by that?

---

I finally figured out what you're looking at. I missed it in the question.

Here's an example using the recursive scheduling:

```
IObservable<char> sequence = Observable.Create<char>(o =>
{
    string message = "hello world!";
    return Scheduler.Default.Schedule<string>(message, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0), (state, schedule) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
        {
            o.OnNext(state[0]);
            schedule(state.Substring(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0));
        }
        else
        {
            o.OnCompleted();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems my questions isn't as clear as I thought it was. Maybe the code is too contrived. The important part of my question is that I am currently reading _Intro To RX Part 4: Scheduling and Threading_ and finding it hard to justify the additional complexity. http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SchedulingAndThreading

Comment: @Gusdor - The additional complexity of what compared to what?

Comment: The additional complexity of recursive scheduling compared to either of our examples. Other engineers are going to have to read this, so what useful features does all that code buy me?

Comment: @Gusdor - Can you let me know what you mean by "recursive scheduling"? I can't see anything that I would call recursive scheduling in your question.

Comment: The section _Recursion_ in the following page >> http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#Recursion

Comment: @Gusdor - What makes them more complex? Because they take parameters like `Action<Action<TimeSpan>>`?

Comment: @Gusdor - I added an example of recursive scheduling.