# Why do I need to dispose of subscriptions after completion?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, idisposable, reactive, object-lifetime

The Intro To RX book describes the return value on OnSubscribe as `IDisposible` and notes that subscriptions should be disposed of when `OnError` and `OnCompleted` are called.

> An interesting thing to consider is that when a sequence completes or
>   errors, you should still dispose of your subscription.
>
> *From [Intro to RX: Lifetime Management, OnError and OnCompleted](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#OnErrorAndOnCompleted)*

**Why is this?**

---

For reference, this is the class I'm currently working on. I'm probably going to submit it to code review at some point.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

/// <summary>
/// Provides a timeout mechanism that will not timeout if it is signalled often enough
/// </summary>
internal class TrafficTimeout
{
    private readonly Action onTimeout;
    private object signalLock = new object();
    private IObserver<Unit> signals;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="TrafficTimeout"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">The duration to wait after receiving signals before timing out.</param>
    /// <param name="onTimeout">The <see cref="Action"/> to perform when the the timeout duration expires.</param>
    public TrafficTimeout(TimeSpan timeout, Action onTimeout)
    {
        // Subscribe to a throttled observable to trigger the expirey
        var messageQueue = new BehaviorSubject<Unit>(Unit.Default);
        IDisposable subscription = null;
        subscription = messageQueue.Throttle(timeout).Subscribe(
        p =>
        {
            messageQueue.OnCompleted();
            messageQueue.Dispose();
        });

        this.signals = messageQueue.AsObserver();
        this.onTimeout = onTimeout;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signals that traffic has been received.
    /// </summary>
    public void Signal()
    {
        lock (this.signalLock)
        {
            this.signals.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The disposable returned by the `Subscribe` extension methods is returned solely to allow you to manually unsubscribe from the observable **before** the observable naturally ends.

If the observable completes - with either `OnCompleted` or `OnError` - then the subscription is already disposed for you.

Try this code:

```
var xs = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    var d = Observable.Return(1).Subscribe(o);
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed!");
        d.Dispose();
    });
});

var subscription = xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

If you run the above you'll see that "Disposed!" is written to the console when the observable completes without you needing call `.Dispose()` on the subscription.

One important thing to note: the garbage collector never calls `.Dispose()` on observable subscriptions, so you **must** dispose of your subscriptions if they have not (or may not have) naturally ended before your subscription goes out of scope.

Take this, for example:

```
var wc = new WebClient();

var ds = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<
        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
        DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= h);

var subscription =
    ds.Subscribe(d =>
        Console.WriteLine(d.EventArgs.Result));
```

The `ds` observable will only attach to the event handler when it has a subscription and will only detach when the observable completes or the subscription is disposed of. Since it is an event handler the observable will never complete because it is waiting for more events, and hence disposing is the only way to detach from the event (for the above example).

When you have a `FromEventPattern` observable that you know will only ever return one value then it is wise to add the `.Take(1)` extension method before subscribing to allow the event handler to automatically detach and then you don't need to manually dispose of the subscription.

Like so:

```
var ds = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<
        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
        DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= h)
    .Take(1);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Gusdor - No trouble. Did you see my example of using recursive scheduling that I added to my answer to your other Rx question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47275900/259769

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, here's an example of the trouble you can run into:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        DumbSubscription();
        Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
}

public void DumbSubscription()
{
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))
        .Subscribe(i => {});
}
```

You will see your memory usage go up forever. Active Rx subscriptions do not get garbage collected and this observable is infinite. Therefore, if you increase the loop limit, or add a delay, and you'll simply have more wasted memory: Nothing will help you except for disposing of those subscriptions.

However, let's say we change the definition of `DumbSubscription` to this:

```
public void DumbSubscription()
{
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))
        .Take(1)
        .Subscribe(i => {});
}
```

The `.Take(1)` addition means that the observable will complete after one interval, so it's no longer infinite. You'll see that your memory usage stabilizes: Subscriptions *tend* to properly dispose of themselves upon completion or exception.

However, that doesn't change the fact that, like any other `IDisposable`, it's a best practice to call `Dispose` (either manually or via `using`) to make sure resources are properly disposed of. Additionally, if you tweak your observable, you can easily run into the memory leak problem pointed out at the beginning.

Comment: In my example class, `OnCompleted` is called on the `BehaviourSubject`, so I guess its safe to assume the sequence isn't infinite. Is it appropriate for you to conclude with an appraisel of the lifetime management in the example code? Alternatively, I have created a code review stack for that purpose >> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180708/mechanism-for-providing-timeout-notifications-when-traffic-ceases.